# Configure Azure CDN caching

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn, microsoft-cdn

I am trying to configure Azure CDN caching (Microsoft Standard), but something does not work for me. 
I pointed CDN to https://yaplex.com and my CDN is configured to https://www.yaplex.com (the whole website under WWW is served from CDN)

When I request the WWW website, I get it back from CDN, **but it looks like CDN does not do any caching**. 
For example, if I make a change to the content and refresh the WWW website, it returns me a version with the content updated.

I am doing the following caching rules, which instructs CDN to cache everything for 5 days but looks like either my rule is wrong or I am doing something wrong.

Can you please help to configure CDN caching for Azure or at least point me in the right direction?

Update: what I am trying to achieve is to serve the WWW version from **CDN cache**, so even if the website is down, users still can open it from CDN.

[image]

Comment: It looks like everything besides the page is served from the cache. I add new column x-cache in the network tool and it shows me "TCP_HIT" for all resources (images, scripts, styles...), but the actual page returns "TCP_MISS".  That is not what I expect, but at least everything else is served from CDN

Comment: Time-to-live (TTL) in a cache that you set/override/mandate has nothing to do with how long your file will stay in the cache before it is evicted because other folks also use the same cache. So unless it is specific feature that you paid for - I wouldn't expect you achieving what you describe. TTL is about permission so to speak, not about guarantee.